# Objective-C UITableView index

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

How do I read always the most upper line (cell.textLabel.text) in a UITableView?

I have two slightly different approaches;

1:

```
UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *cellText2 = cell2.textLabel.text;
NSLog (@" cellText2 = %@", cellText2);
```

2:

```
NSMutableString *newidea = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSLog (@"newidea = %@", newidea);
```

Both codes are inside the method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

self.array is same array that fills up the tableView.

The former approach always shows text from the sixth cell. The latter approach always shows text from the fifth cell. In my tableview there is four cells at a time.@

What I want to get is the text from the most upper cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have the wrong approach. You don't read values from cells, instead you let the cells read values from your data array. A cell can always have an arbitrary value since they are reused. Even if you have 30 "cells" in your table view there may only be 5 existing actual cells. When a cell goes outside the table view when you scroll, it is moved to the bottom and reused as the next cell. That's why you always have to set the values for each cell on the index path.

Instead you should get the value in the first cell from your data array if you have one. When the table view asks what title the cell att `indexPath.row == 0` should have, you give it to it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, for example from an array called "_cellTitles" containing 30 strings for 30 different cells.

If you want to get the text from the "most upper" visible cell, then you can call `indexPathsForVisibleRows` on the table view. The first object in the returned array is the index path for the most upper visible cell. You can check the string in your array at index indexPath.row.

Example:

```
NSArray *visibleRows = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
NSIndexPath *firstVisibleCell = [visibleRows objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *firstVisibleCellTitle = [_myDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is correct that I let cells read values from data array. Could you provide a code line example for `indexPathsForVisibleRows`?

Comment: Thanks. The two latter code lines did not work, because at startup visibleRows is empty. When I scroll, then the array fills up. I need filled array right after startup without scrolling.

Comment: Do you call [tableView reloadData] when the table is loaded?

Comment: @ac with visibleCells, the array is filled up right away, but NSString *visString = [vis objectAtIndex:0] makes the app crash. vis is NSArray *vis [self.tableView visibleCells]; Oh, where should I put this reload line?

Comment: @ac I added this line after `return cell;`, but nothing changes.

Comment: return cell; ends the function, so any code placed there will not run. Either way you shouldn't run this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath since that's the function the table view calls for every cell it wants to display. Maybe you should follow some of Apples tutorials on table views to get a better understanding of them before trying this.

Comment: you are right. I was tired. I had this reload line in the end of the method viewDidLoad, but it did not help. Anyway, thanks for pointing me in right direction with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to read from first row, instead of indexPath just say 1 there. That way it will always read from the first row.