# Objective-C How to read text of an array of visibleCells?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

My code follows as:

```
NSArray *vis = [tableView1 visibleCells];
    NSLog (@"vis %@", vis);
```

And I get:

```
2012-07-04 21:16:44.564 xxx[1933:12e03] vis (
    "<UITableViewCell: 0xb2dcc80; frame = (0 0; 320 80); text = 'xxx1'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xb2dcd60>>",
    "<UITableViewCell: 0x635ea10; frame = (0 80; 320 80); text = 'xxx2'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x6353620>>",
    "<UITableViewCell: 0xb2ddca0; frame = (0 160; 320 80); text = 'xxx3'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xb2ddc70>>",
    "<UITableViewCell: 0x635f7d0; frame = (0 240; 320 80); text = 'xxx4'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x635f650>>"
```

When I write:

```
NSString *aText = [vis objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog (@"aText %@", aText);
```

I get invariably a warning:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Is this a kind of multidimensional array? If yes, how can I extract only text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array returned by `visibleCells` contains `UITableViewCell` objects, and not `NSString` objects. You can see that in the output of your `NSLog(@"vis %@", vis);`.

To get the strings, you'd need to ask the `UITableViewCell`s for them.

In other words:

```
NSString *aText = [[[vis objectAtIndex:0] textLabel] text];
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I have another question, why can I not use this string in string comparison? The app always crashed when I use aText, but works perfectly with other strings.

Comment: @wagashi: how are you comparing the strings? `[@"test" isEqualToString:aText]` should work...

Comment: `[totalArray addObjectsFromArray:[firstArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF contains[c] %@)", aText]]];` is the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You should rather use:

```
NSArray *cells = [tableView1 visibleCells];
if ([cells count] > 0) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [cells objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *text = cell.textLabel.text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help regarding if array count is more than 0. However other lines are not right approach to get text, I think.

Comment: I've edited the post to use textLabel instead of titleLabel which doesn't exist. As for the old cell.text property, it has been deprecated since iOS 3.0 and shouldn't be used.

Comment: I understand and it is probably correct for other uses. But please see my another question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299924/objective-c-uitableview-index   That is why I need to extract text of visibleCells, not cell.textLabel.text. Thanks :)